# Check if PDO Query has Fetched all Rows Matching Where Conditions

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm a novice PHP programmer in need of help. Is there a way to check if there are no remaining records within a PDO while loop? Within the while loop I'm adding up one of the fields and have an if statement to check if the total has eclipsed a variable.
Within the if statement I do all the data manipulations. My problem is if there aren't enough records to eclipse the variable I never get to the data manipulations.

Code:

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE ...  ");
while ($rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$add_column = $rows['number'];
$total_column = $total_column + $add_column;
//Other Stuff
if ($total_column > $variable_balance) {// Would like to also check here if there are no remaining records to fetch.
    //Do Stuff
    exit;
}
}
```

Comment: Perform the actions after the while loop. You will only get to that code when you run out of rows.

Comment: I'm performing the actions in the while loop because I'm adding the numbers from each record in the while loop.

Comment: The total variable will still be available outside the loop. PHP variables are not scoped to the loop. Any variables declared inside the loop will be available outside. So you can do all your adding inside the loop and then perform some action outside with those variables.

Comment: I can't exit the loop outside the loop though. The loop will keep going even though the total eclipsed the variable. The if statement outside the loop won't run until the loop is finished.

Comment: I don't why I was fretting over this just to save a few lines of text. I ended up just adding the same if statement but  using > 0 along with the same data manipulation code outside the loop.

Comment: Ended up putting all the data manipulations and tasks in a separate file and then only put an include statement in the 2 if statements.

Answer (score -1):

You can make sure that you fetch all records by using `$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` instead of `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

If you want to use fetchAll you can use a for-loop

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
foreach($rows as $row) {
$add_column  = $row['number'];
//other stuff
}
}
```

This will automatically perform the actions for all records.

Comment: your example says `fetch`, not `fetchAll`.

Comment: That's the point. First I say he can use `fetchAll()` after that I say "if you want to use fetch you can also use a for-loop"

Comment: But `fetch` would return 1 row. Your foreach loop would just loop over the columns in that one row. If you used `fetchAll` you could then foreach over the entire result set as you have above. You can't really use a foreach loop like that with fetch to loop over rows.

Comment: You are completely right, I was being an idiot, thanks

Comment: I don't need to add all the rows in the select. I only need add rows until I hit a number. Then I no longer need any rows and it's time to exit the loop.